# Decrypting string from Android app in PHP

Tags: php, android, cryptography

I'm facing a problem when it comes to decrypting a string that is sent from an Android application. It works fine as long as non-special characters such as æ, ø, å is written. If I add one of those they are shown as '?'.

Here is how the string is encrypted (Java):

```
/*Constructor*/
public DataCrypt()
{
   ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

   keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

   try
   {
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
   }
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
   {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
   catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
   {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
{
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
       throw new Exception("Empty string");

    byte[] encrypted = null;

    try
    {
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

      encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {                       
      throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }      
    return encrypted;
}
```

And here is how the string is decrypted:

```
function decrypt($code)
{
  $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
  $iv = $this->iv;

  $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);
  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);

  $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);

  return utf8_decode(trim($decrypted));
}

protected function hex2bin($hexdata)
{
  $bindata = '';

  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2)
  {
    $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
  }
  return $bindata;
}

function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text))
        return false;

    if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad)
        return false;

    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}


$Username = pkcs5_unpad($crypto->decrypt($Username)); //$crypto is an instance of the cryptography class which holds the methods.
echo $Username.'<br/>'; /*Print ??? for special characters like æ, ø, å*/
```

Hope someone has an idea on how I can fix the problem so it is possible to write ø æ å as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you're using `ord`, which is ascii only - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Comment: Most possibly your encryption and decryption work fine - I guess it is just the output of your `echo $Username.'<br/>'` that is UTF8, but is interpreted by the client as some siingle-byte encoding. Try `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`in youd HTML document head!

Comment: @therefromhere I thought so too, but he only uses it for padding

Comment: @EugenRieck ah, fair enough, was just skimming the code.

Comment: @EugenRieck Have this in my header:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
And when I try to add the value into the database it just skips the ? so they are not inserted at all, just the non-special characters.

Comment: Adding the value into the DB needs a UTF8-enabled Database table - are you sure you have one? You could also echo the string as bytes and manually check an example to make sure

Comment: @EugenRieck: Yeah, it's enabled for the database as well. Tested with a string containing special characters. But I can try writing it out as bytes and check the result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the use of `utf8_decode()` which the php docs define as `Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1`. This implies, that non-iso characters are mutilated. Try to simply remove the `utf8_decode()`